# Crosswalk - missing aapt and aapt.com

Tags: javascript, android, sdk

I'm trying to use crosswalk to create simple application for android. I instaled Android SDK, Ant, JDK and python ([instruction](https://crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/getting_started/windows_host_setup)). Now I'm trying to build an application and I used [Crosswalk instruction](https://crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/getting_started/build_an_application) to create HTML and JSON file. 
Unfortunately next step is not working. I'm using `python make_apk.py --manifest=xwalk-simple/manifest.json` to build everything but I have an error:

```
There doesn't exist aapt in [folder with android sdk]
There doesn't exist aapt.com in [folder with android sdk]
Use aapt.exe in [folder with android sdk]
```

How to fix that (or how to use aapt.exe)? I don't know Android SDK, but I tried to copy aapt.exe from built-tools to platform-tools and it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

It is a workaround rather than a real solution of the problem, but try to use the beta version (currently 9.38.*) instead of the 7.38.* stable release. I experienced exactly the same problem as you and switching to 9.38.208.1 resolved the issue immediately, without any further configuration. It works like a charm.